# Equal to operator "==" is behaving like assignment operator "="

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I am facing a very strange problem.

**- I have an if condition:**

```
if((IN_SYNC == sync_flag) || (cycle_number == spi_slot_number))
```

Before the condition, the variable "spi_slot_number" is '7' and after the if condition it was turned to '0' (which is the value of "cycle_number") !!!

Does any one knows how can such thing happen ?!

**Important notes:**

1- My code is in C language.

2- I checked the stack before and after the condition to make sure no stack corruption happening.

3- My program is one thread program, so no interrupts or other threads can interrupt.

4- If I commented the if condition , every thing goes fine.

5- I don't know how to generate the assembly code ...

Comment: Typically this is from undefined behavior and/or threading problems.

Comment: We need more code , not just an `if` statement.

Comment: Post more of your code. No way I'm believing in that.

Comment: Not only post the source code for the entire function this code is in, but also post the assembly output of the compiler, and the exact version and target of the compiler you're using.

Comment: *"after the if condition it was turned to '0' (which is the value of "cycle_number")"* how else did you expect to satisfy the `if` statement's condition?

Comment: I'd address your confusion to debugger misinterpretation of release optimized code.

Comment: It might happen if the `spi_slot_number` is not used elsewhere (or the compiler is believing it is not used), and the the optimization just using some temporary register to store it's value, which is overwritten afterwards.

Comment: I don't think so, because at least it is used in the printfs which I am using for tracking its value

Comment: Please add `printf` statements that show your problem. Also, please try reducing your code to the minimum possible, so that the problem still exists (make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also, please update your question - `if(cycle_number == spi_slot_number)` doesn't appear in the "exact code".

Comment: How to get the assembly output of the compiler ?!

Comment: I'd start with the MCVE before the assembly output -- assembly output will be clearer and simpler to read, after all, when generated from a truly minimal example.

Comment: @RamySameh, if your compiler is gcc, use the `-S` argument to compile but not assemble.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, you haven't shared enough code to actually identify where your problem is.  One thought that occurred to me however is the `IN_SYNC` identifier.  It's a standard coding convention to put macros in all caps, and if it is a macro, it's possible that it's doing the dirty deed. Check for definition of `IN_SYNC`.

One other thing -- your `if` test has two tests, separated by an || operator. Try breaking the two tests apart to see which one is causing your side effect. Something like this:

```
printf("%d \n", spi_slot_number);
if (IN_SYNC == sync_flag) { 
    /* do nothing */
    }
printf("after IN_SYNC test %d \n", spi_slot_number);
if (cycle_number == spi_slot_number) {
    /* do nothing */
    }
printf("after cycle_number test %d \n", spi_slot_number);
```

Comment: I did, and the condition "cycle_number == spi_slot_number" was the one causing the problem.

Comment: If this is the Wind River embedded compiler, try examine the PreProcessor output (use the -E command line option) to confirm there's nothing you don't expect going on. If that looks OK, then generate the Assembly output using the -S command line option and examine the machine code. If that looks OK, you either have faulty hardware OR you've found a bug in the compiler toolchain (maybe the linker is to blame?) -- and you should submit a bug report to Wind River.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do comparision on temporal copy of spi_slot_number? Does it work as expected?

```
void GetData(slot_id_T spi_slot_number, uint8_t* data_received,
         uint16_t data_length, uint8_t data_is_valid_flag)
 {
     uint8_t cycle_number;
     slot_id_T copy = spi_slot_number; // <- ADDED

     cycle_number = GetCycleNumber() + 1;
     if(cycle_number > LAST_CYCLE)
     {
         cycle_number = 0;
     }

     printf("%d \n", spi_slot_number);

     if((IN_SYNC == sync_flag) || (cycle_number == copy)) // <- CHANGE
     {
         printf("%d \n", spi_slot_number);

         switch(data_is_valid_flag)
         {
         case DATA_IS_VALID:
             SendData(spi_slot_number, p_buffer, data_length);
             break;

         case DATA_IS_NOT_VALID:
             IndicateDataNotValid(spi_slot_number, p_buffer, data_length);
             break;

         default:
             /* Do Nothing */
             break;
         }
      }
}
```